# Specify IPSEC port range using ipsec-tools

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipsec

Is it possible to require IPSEC on a port *range* ?
I want to require IPSEC for all incoming connections except a few public ports like 80 and 443, but don't want to restrict outgoing connections.

My SPD rules would look like:

```
spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0[80] tcp -P in none;
spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0[443] tcp -P in none;
spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0[0....32767] tcp -P in esp/require/transport;
```

In `setkey` manpage I see **IP** ranges, but no mention of **port** ranges.

(The idea is to use IPSEC as a sort of VPN to protect internal communications between multiple servers. Instead of configuring permissions basing on source IPs, or configuring specific ports, I want to demand IPSEC on **anything** which is not meant to be public - I feel it's less error-prone this way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, while you can indeed specify a IP range, there's no way to specify a port range.
This means that you need to enter a rule for each port, or more simply you can use a script for that e.g.:

```
perl -e 'print "spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0[$_] tcp -P in esp/require/transport;\n" for (1..32767)' >run.sh
```

I assume that those servers are not located in the same datacenter. This actually can cause serious efficiency problems, unless there's a fast connection between those servers and/or you choose a fast encryption algorithm for IPSEC.

[Performance comparison of IPsec and TLS Based VPNs](http://iceta.sk/proceedings/iceta2011_truchly.pdf)

Comment: Why there's an efficiency problem with IPSEC, and why it related to servers location ? I thought IPSEC should be roughly as fast as any other encryption solutions, say OpenVPN or SSH or TLS or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I wonder _why_ they didn't implement port ranges... Don't feel good with adding 32k separate rules. I think I will use iptables to require ipsec on a certain ports (iptables may have rules based on ipsec status).

Comment: Well, if there're latency/bandwidth issues using any kind of VPN (IPSEC/OpenVPN) will make things much worse. See this link for performance comparison of IPsec and TLS Based VPNs: http://www.iceta.sk/proceedings/iceta2011_truchly.pdf

Comment: 1. Thanks a lot for the link. 2. I think all the slowness they report originates from CPU/RAM only and is completely unrelated to the _connection_ latency/bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, CPU/RAM is probably the main factor of efficieny issues. For any VPN software there's always a traffic overhead though - VPN connection consumes more bandwidth than non-encrypted connection. As for the latency issues I can tell you from my own experience that there're some serious issues when using VPN on high latency connection.